# XML Parser for robospice-google-http-client?

Tags: android, xml, robospice, google-http-client

I want to parse XML response using robospice-google-http-client. I can parse json response as follows.

```
HttpRequest request = getHttpRequestFactory()//
                .buildGetRequest( new GenericUrl( url) );
        request.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());
        return request.execute().parseAs( getResultType() );
```

how to parse XML?
I tried this

```
request.setParser(new XmlObjectParser(new XmlNamespaceDictionary().set("", "test")));
```

but an error is thrown saying

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid XML: no alias declared for namesapce <>; work-around by setting XML namepace directly by calling the set method of com.google.api.client.xml.XmlNamespaceDictionary
```

i tired setting namespace but no luck

Comment: can you provide example of your xml and POJO classes? I can't make parsing work in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this by setting new XmlNamespaceDictionary().set("", "")